# canceling settext() to see original textview()

Tags: android, textview

**I want to cancel  settext() in button1 when I clicked Button2. I want to see original text in textview().**

```
    buton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buton1);
    buton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buton2);
    cikti  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cikti);

    buton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            cikti.setText("You clicked!");

        }
    });

    buton2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Please do not self-vandalize your posts

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
buton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buton1);
    buton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buton2);
    cikti  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cikti);
    final String originalText = cikti.getText().toString();

    buton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            cikti.setText("You clicked!");

        }
    });

    buton2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            cikti.setText(originalText);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding what you want is this :

```
buton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buton1);
    buton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buton2);
    cikti  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cikti);

    buton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            cikti.setText("You clicked!");

        }
    });

    buton2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          cikti.setText("");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to "cancel" a change like that, the only way is if you save a string with the text you want and apply it:

```
buton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buton1);
buton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buton2);
cikti  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cikti);
String myString = "my text";
cikti.setText(myString);

buton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        cikti.setText("You clicked!");

    }
});

buton2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        cikti.setText(myString);
    }
});
```

}

I assume that the way your code is structured you are setting a string with an xml file, in that case you can do this:

```
buton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buton1);
buton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buton2);
cikti  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cikti);

buton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        cikti.setText("You clicked!");

    }
});

buton2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        cikti.setText(R.string.myString);
    }
});
```

}